# .NET and Lotus Notes Interop

Tags: .net, interop, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I've Lotus Notes database file (.nsf) at some location, let's say: http://intranet.mycompany.com/somewhere/data.nsf

Is it possible in any way to read from that location using any .NET language?

Comment: What version of Lotus Domino/Notes are you using?  Do you have the lotus notes client installed on the machine that is going to run the .net code?  Can you give more details on what you want to do?

Comment: @Carlos: I was given a link like http://intranet.mycompany.com/somewhere/data.nsf, and I've Lotus Notes 7 installed on my machine. Also I do have Lotus Domino Objects and Lotus Notes Automation Classes in Add referece/COM tab in VS. Is it possible to get data from that .nsf given only this link?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at these resources:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/index.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lotusnoteintegrator.aspx
- http://www.builderau.com.au/architect/database/soa/Create-an-ODBC-connection-to-a-Lotus-Notes-database/0,339024547,320282240,00.htm

Comment: The first link to www.ibm.com/developerworks... is broken

Answer (score 5):

1. You can use the ReadViewEntries URL option and that returns data as XML --> http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/855dc7fcfd5fec9a85256b870069c0ab/63d772b44948d4848525704a003f6544?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,readviewentries
2. You can use the COM classes to access the database.  Actually the first link that @Konamiman posted covers both solutions  --> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/index.html

Answer (score 1):

My humble opinion for those who face such a task would be not to bother with direct access to LN data (at least i haven't heard of any decent C# dev for Lotus Notes), but consider the following:

1) dump LN data into a relational database (IBM DB2, MS SQL Server etc.) with the help of LEI (Lotus Enterprise Integeration) or a custom tool, where you can use it any way you want, say in ORM for ASP.NET, even bi-directional.
This makes sense when you migrate or have a schedule for data exchange.

2) for lesser amount of data with sporadic access i'd develop a WebService or some in the Lotus Notes database.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you're accessing the database over HTTP only, because this is how you provided its location.
So, for the current and older versions of Domino server, you can access the different database elements using the [Domino URL syntax](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Redbooks%3A%20Best%20Practices%20for%20Domino%208.0%20Web%20Application%20Development#action=openDocument&res_title=07302008084503AMKMKGXS.htm&content=pdcontent) which provide access to design elements in addition to data documents.

And starting with Domino 9, you can also access the data using REST requests using the [Domino Access Services (DAS)](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api), which provide all the standard CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) commands that you need, i.e. POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, and PATCH. Remember that you need to enable the database and its views to be accessed by DAS before you can run your requests.

The links provided give you all the information you need.

Comment: Here are instructions for enabling the database and views to be accessed via DAS: [link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Enabling_Domino_Data_Service_on_a_database_das901&content=apicontent)