# c# code to send the mail using lotus notes in .net webservice

Tags: asp.net, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am currently working on a functionality to send the email from asp.net C# code using lotus Notes.can any one tell me the initial requirements for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Domino COM classes.  You should be aware that if your code is running as a 64 bit application, this is [not supported](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291) by IBM Lotus Software, however it can be made to work for most purposes.  You will find several questions about this subject here already on StackOverflow, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558640/net-and-lotus-notes-interop/1558661#1558661) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416308/is-a-comexception-of-0x80040154-always-class-not-registered).

Comment: i dont have a lotus note client software.Is it required to send mail using lotus notes creditials?

Comment: i got following error while sending (client.(Send(Message)) mail. "The remote name could not be resolved: 'servername'".

Comment: You can't use the Domnino COM classes without installing and configuring either Notes Notes client or Lotus Domino server software on the machine where the code is running.

Comment: thanks Richard Schwartz.What about smtp protocol?would it support Lotus notes server?

Comment: Yes, a Lotus Domino server can support SMTP.  Some organizations only enable the SMTP listener on specific servers, there might also be authentication requirements, and the anti-relay configuration might have to be changed in order to allow this, so you should discuss this with your organization's Lotus Notes and Domino administration team.